# docker-compose is not mapping ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have problem with dockerizing Vue.js app. After `docker-compose up --build` app normally starts, but I can't access it (`docker ps` shows that no port has been mapped). Vue.js app starts normally at :8080. I can't find why it's not mapped by Docker:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:10.15-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run dev
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - 8082:8080

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Try to remove container and run docker-compose again. There is  a chance you didn't specify ports in some previous version of docker-compose so it uses the same container. You can also run docker-compose up with some flag which will rebuild containers.

Comment: Thanks, you mean `--force-recreate` flag? If so - I did it along with manual removal of container and still the same thing. If that matters - container get's random name instead of `frontend`

Comment: I don’t think your container is actually running.  The Dockerfile you show doesn’t have a `CMD`, for example.

Comment: When I use `docker exec -it container_name_here /bin/ash` I am actually attaching to container. Also container is on the list when used `docker ps`